# Searching contact details patend CN102853400 B

Tags: patent-services

does anyone know how i can find the contact details from chinese patent holder for this patent CN102853400 B
would be great
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you pull up [CN102853200B](https://patents.google.com/patent/CN102853400B/en) on patents.google.com you can click on the Espacenet link. From there you can see that the assignee is "SHENZHEN KAPATA PHOTOELECTRIC CO.,LTD". Looking them up on Google yields the following website: http://www.led-purchase.com/5141523/index.html. On that page, is a button which purports to allow you to send a message to the company. It also lists the contact details as follows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a patent search engine supported by SIPO officially:
http://epub.sipo.gov.cn/index.action

You can use Chrome and translate the page into English, though of course the results are often not entirely reliable or even understandable.

As for CN102853400B, its rights are held by Tianman（田满), a private person, as the result of a patent rights transfer. Before the transfer, the rights were held by 深圳市科普达光电股份有限公司 aka 深圳市深博创照明股份有限公司 aka 深圳市深博创照明股份有限公司 (all these three names are the same company; it changed its name during the past years).

As for Tianman（田满; generally speaking this is a male name in China) his address is 435300 湖北省蕲春县张榜镇塘坻村五组, which is typical address in China mainland country.

Comment: I submitted an edit suggestion to remove your email address. Email solicitations are not generally a good idea on this site, as we like for further discussion and clarification to happen here in the open where others, too, can benefit from the process and its results.